Saving Excel document removes the chart
I am using OpenPyXL for processing, there are only 2 lines of code:
workbook = load_workbook(filename='input.xlsx', keep_vba=True, rich_text=True)
# I will do operator here, but there is an error, so I comment this line
workbook.save('output.xlsx')

Then I get the output with less size:

When I try to open output.xlsx, this notification appears:

The chart was removed by Microsoft Excel. Sometimes I cannot open it in Microsoft Excel, but LibreOffice can open it with no error.
Left: input.xlsx, right: output.xlsx. The chart was removed and Microsoft Excel reports an error:

The alert:

Often my input file has ~ 4 sheets, a chart, and 1 sheet has data. My task is to write data to one sheet, I do not care about the others. I want to get one of these solutions:

Allow OpenPyXL to read the charts the right way.
Make OpenPyXL read a specific sheet, and other sheets will be passed.
Avoid OpenPyXL decrease the size of the file (I think OpenPyXL does it for performance).

Using another library/language is the last option.

Are you using the latest version of Openpyxl? If you run your code on an XLSX file, you'll produce a XLSM file with an 'xlsx' extension which Excel will fail to open, but only due to the extension being wrong.

What @moken says: Why keep_vba=True for a *.xlsx file? A *.xlsx cannot contain VBA. A file containing VBA must be named *.xlsm and has a different content type than a *.xlsx file.

@moken I am using version 3.2.0b1 openpyxl, the input is valid .xlsx file. The default load_workbook function with: workbook = load_workbook(filename='input.xlsx') still not work, so I make keep_vba=True

@AxelRichter I've update the description:  Result: the left of image is input.xlsx, and the right is output.xlsx, you can see, there is an error occurred.

@moken I said it the valid .xlsx because I opened input.xlsx file with MS Excel

In any case, keep_vba=True is wrong for a *.xlsx. For me openpyxl works fine and keeps drawings and charts when present. So we would need the input file you are using to be able to help.

@AxelRichter Yes, there is the valid input.xlsx, I deleted other sheets.

Technically 3.2.0.b1 is not released, however you may have gotten it if you updated Openpyxl recently. The actual latest released version is 3.1.4. Either way the release you have should not impact existing Charts.

@moken can you try with that excel file I provided? Just load_workbook and save input

On a first look at the Excel file, there is custom XML included which Openpyxl is not retaining after saving. This is one reason that the file size drops, (though this 'input.xlsx' is not 665KB, rather 188KB). The charts are not deleted but obviously the dropping of the custom xml is causing them to be rejected (then deleted) by Excel. I'm not actually sure of what Openpyxl's stance is on this and no direct experience, other than the indication with this file that Openpyxl is dropping it. You may be better to raise the issue with Openpyxl Dev. They may comment here and then again they may not.

The problem is that your charts are combination charts. The chart plot area contains a bar chart and a line chart. Each of these charts has one series where the first series, which is the bar chart series, has idx 0 and order 1 while the second series, which is the line chart series, has idx 1 and order 0. The order is the series order in Select Data Source of the chart. There the line chart series is before the bar chart series.
Seems openpyxl reader does not handle combination charts properly. It reads the first bar chart in plot area and re-indexes it's series. Other possible series of additional charts in plot area stay unchanged for idx and order. And because the reader only finds one chart series in first bar chart in plot area, this series get idx 0 and order 0 then, since it is the only one series known. The following not considered line chart series stays idx 1 and order 0. But then both series in plot area have the same order 0 and that leads to the error while opening in Excel.
Workaround:
Change the series order in Select Data Source of the charts. For left chart "Cost" before "CVs". For right chart "IMP" before "CPC".  Then bar chart series has has idx 0 and order 0 and line chart series has has idx 1 and order 1. That works then.

If you don't want to change the source file, the following code should also work:
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("./input.xlsx", rich_text=True)

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    for chart in sheet._charts:
        idx = 0
        order = 0
        for subChart in chart._charts:
            print(subChart)
            for ser in subChart.ser:
                print(ser.idx)
                print(ser.order)
                ser.idx = idx
                idx += 1
                ser.order = order
                order += 1
                print(ser.idx)
                print(ser.order)

wb.save("./output.xlsx")

It re-indexes and re-orders all series in all sub-charts for each main-chart in worksheet.

It really work with me, very impressive! Thank you
